# wikitravel - how to get image link

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have got a full xml dump of wikitravel.org. Now I want to get the URLs from

```
[[Image:Iwamotoji PilgrimGirl.JPG|thumb|print=full|Pilgrim traveling on foot, [[Kubokawa]]]]
```

There used to be an [API](http://wikitravel.org/wiki/en/api.php) for this. But seems its been disabled now.

While doing some R&D I found that the URLs are not in specific pattern.

[Chicago Main image](http://wikitravel.org/upload/shared//b/b0/Skyline_from_Millenium_Park.jpg)

[Chicago city Bus](http://wikitravel.org/upload/shared//1/13/Ctabus.jpg)

Can you pleaselet me know how can I get the actual URLs (thumb as well as the regular) to the images in an aritical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much all the content of Wikitravel has been [forked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikitravel#Community_fork.2C_2012) over to [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Main_Page), which *does* have a functional [API](http://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php).  So you could just [query the Wikivoyage API](http://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Image%3aIwamotoji%20PilgrimGirl.JPG&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url) instead.

Comment: Thanks Karonen for sharing this great information. I hope this will help the community. However the solution given by is also valid as long as one insists to use WikiTravel.

Currently we are using the solution by md5 but surely shall consider migrating to WikiVoyage

Answer (score 2):

After spending some more time on R&D. I found the following algorithm

```
$base_url = "http://wikitravel.org/upload/shared/";
$image_name = "XYZ 123.JPG";
$image_name = str_replace(" ","_",$image_name);
$md5 = md5($image_name); // MD5 hash of the image
$dir = substr($md5, 0,1).'/'.substr($md5, 0,2);
$image_url = $base_url . $dir . $image_name;
```

Source: [*What are the strangely named components in file paths?* from Commons FAQ](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_strangely_named_components_in_file_paths.3F)

I hope it will help others.